# How to trigger a modal on submit button & redirect Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form and I want the submit button to submit the form and redirect but I want a modal to come up at the same time and make the user wait while the app does it's thing(takes about 35 seconds). How can I get the submit button to submit AND bring up the modal.

```
<%= form_for @tenant, url: wizard_path, method: :put, validate: true do |f| %>
    Blah...Blah...
  <div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit "Submit Report Information" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pleaseWaitDialog" %>
  <!---Waiting Modal--->
    <div class="modal hide" id="pleaseWaitDialog" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
      <div class="modal-header">
          <h1>Processing...<small>May take up to 1 minute</small></h1>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="progress progress-striped active">
              <div class="bar" style="width: 100%;"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller although it is a (wicked gem) step controller, this is the last step in a form process.

```
class Tenants::ReportStepsController < ApplicationController
  include Wicked::Wizard
  before_filter :authenticate_tenant!


  steps :basic_info, :bill_input, :upsell_input, :report_pay, :bank_trans, :confirm_info

  def show
    @tenant = current_tenant
    @tenant.build_bill if @tenant.bill.blank?
    ...
    @tenant.build_upsell if @tenant.upsell.blank?
    ...
    end
    @tenant.build_transaction if @tenant.transaction.blank?
    render_wizard
  end

 def update
    ...
 end

private

  def finish_wizard_path
    @tenant = current_tenant
    @tenant.build_report if @tenant.report.blank?
    @tenant.build_api_aggregation if @tenant.api_aggregation.blank?
    @tenant.api_aggregation.save
    @tenant.report.save
    GetTransactionsWorker.perform_in(6.minutes, @tenant.id.to_s)
    TransAggregationWorker.perform_in(7.minutes, @tenant.id.to_s)
    <!---I assume calling the modal in the controller would happen here ---->
    tenants_dashboard_path
  end
```

Comment: if its redirects, then u can do it in a controller. so kinds when your functions success (processing done) then trigger that redirect  to that page ITS IN BACK END. And in the front end just add some javascript, to show user its processing...

Comment: yes it does redirect.

Comment: How do I call the modal in the controller?

Comment: post your rails controller method, probably someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this we will add two div id in the CSS file.
 
One is the **#content** id and second is **#loading**.

```
div#content {
  display: none;
} 


div#loading {
 top: 200 px;
 margin: auto;
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 1000;
 width: 160px;
 height: 24px;
 background: url(loadingimage.gif) no-repeat;
 cursor: wait;
}
```

loadingimage.gif can be any image that display loading animation

Now add these div id into your html page as follow

```
<div id="loading"></div>
   <div id="content">your html content here......</div>
```

Now add the following javascript code into head section of your html   page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
     function preloader(){
         document.getElementById("loading").style.display = "none";
         document.getElementById("content").style.display = "block";
     }//preloader
     window.onload = preloader;
// ]]></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@supermeA You want to open modal popup when user click on submit button? then you want to do something and then submit that data to controller?

Comment: I want to click on a submit button and when you click on submit while the app is processing a processing model comes up telling the user to wait and then once the app is finish processing it redirects the person to the page it was intended to redirect to